# Undefined variable radio-button issue - where to place isset check

Tags: php, mysql, forms, radio-button

**Problem**: I have a search-form with a radio button, which uses PHP to post to a database. If the radio button is left unchecked, I'd still like the rest of the search to run. However, it doesn't, because it creates an undefined variable issue.

**How I imagine a solution:** I've read up online (particularly here on stackoverflow), and it seems this should be fixed by checking isset, !empty or similar.

**So, why are you posting?** I've placed the check multiple places in my code, but either the rest of the search doesn't run, or it runs but leaves the column blank (i.e. not displaying database information for the variable the radio button refers to).

**What I've tried:** This was my latest attempt. It still produces the error, and also, even if it would work, I think it might change the value in the results table, so it would be different from the actual value in the database.

"difficulty" and "usedbefore" are the radio buttons in my code.

```
if (empty($_POST['difficulty']) && empty($_POST['usedbefore'])) {
        $difficulty = null;
        $usedbefore = null;}
        else {
            $difficulty = $_POST['difficulty'];
            $usedbefore = $_POST['usedbefore'];
```

**Tldr; Where should I place the isset (or similar) check to avoid the undefined variable problem for radio buttons, and still have the rest of the code run?**

HTML form-code:

```
<h1>Søk etter spørsmål</h1>
   
<form action="Search.php" method="post">
    <div class="container_search_criteria">
        <label>Quizspørsmål</label> <input type="text" id="search-question" name="question" title="Quizsspørsmål" placeholder="Søk etter spørsmål">
        <label>Kategori:</label> <select name="category"> 
            <option value="Finkultur">Finkultur</option>
            <option value="Geografi">Geografi</option>
            <option value="Historie">Historie</option>
            <option value="Livsstil">Livsstil</option>
            <option value="Natur & Vitenskap">Natur & Vitenskap</option>
            <option value="Populærkultur">Populærkultur</option>
            <option value="Samfunnsfag">Samfunnsfag</option>
            <option value="Sport & Spill">Sport & Spill</option>
        </select>
            <label>Sub-kategori</label><input type="text" name="subcategory" class="subcat" id="add-subcategori" title="Sub-kategori" placeholder="Legg til sub-kategori">
            <label>Vanskelighetsgrad: </label>
                <ul class="difficulty">
                <li>1</li>
                <li><input type="range" id="points" name="difficulty" min="1" max="5"></li>
                <li>5</li>   
                </ul>
            <label>Har du brukt spørsmålet før?</label>
                <ul class="usedbefore">
                    <li><input type="radio" name="usedbefore" value="Ja"></li>
                    <li>Ja</li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="usedbefore" value="Nei"></li>
                    <li>Nei</li>
                </ul>
             <label>Hvis ja:</label>
                <ul class="details_usedbefore">
                    <li>Sted</li>
                    <li><input type="text" class="input_usedbefore" name="search-place" id="search-place" title="Sted brukt før" placeholder="Legg til sted"></li>
                    <li>Dato</li>
                    <li><input type="date" class="input_usedbefore" name="search-date"  id="search-date" title="Dato brukt før"></li>
                </ul>
                <button name="submit" class="main_search_button">Søk</button>
                <a id="button_link" href="index.htm"><input type="submit" class="secondary_search_button" value="Avbryt"></a>
    
                </div> <!--End form container-->


</div> <!-- End question form container-->

</form>    

<?php
        include('includes/search.php');
    ?>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);


$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "quiz_test";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $question = $_POST['question'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $sub_category = $_POST['subcategory'];

    if (empty($_POST['difficulty']) && empty($_POST['usedbefore'])) {
        $difficulty = null;
        $usedbefore = null;}
        else {
            $difficulty = $_POST['difficulty'];
            $usedbefore = $_POST['usedbefore'];

        if ($question != "" or $category != "" or $sub_category != "" or $difficulty != "" or $usedbefore != "" ) {
            $query = "Select * FROM questions WHERE question LIKE '%$question%' AND category LIKE '%$category%' AND subcategory LIKE '%$sub_category%' AND Difficulty LIKE '%$difficulty%' AND UsedBefore LIKE '%$usedbefore%'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if ($count > 0) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $question = $row ['question'];
                    $category = $row ['category'];
                    $sub_category = $row ['subcategory'];
                    $difficulty = isset($row['difficulty']);
                    $usedbefore = isset($row['usedbefore']);
                ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $question;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $category;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $sub_category;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $difficulty; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $usedbefore;?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            }
            }
        } 
        else {
            echo "<h1>" . 'Ingen treff' . "</h1>"; 
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the error, and what variable name is it referring to?

Comment: You are checking if _both_ are empty at the same time. If that is not the case, then you try to assign `$difficulty = $_POST['difficulty']; $usedbefore = $_POST['usedbefore'];` - but _one_ of those might still be not set at this point then. You should check both separately.

Comment: @04FS Notice: Line 24 right now. The "=null" on line 14/15 blanks out the column, but if I remove it, I also get there.

Comment: As I said, you have to handle them both separately, not in one go. You are trying to access _both_ of those POST parameters, in case they were not _both_ empty. That still leaves the possibility that _one_ of them was empty.

Comment: @04FS Yeah, sorry, I was working on a solution and forgot to address your second comment. When I try to separate them, the error doesn't appear, but the code doesn't work. ```if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $question = $_POST['question'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $sub_category = $_POST['subcategory'];

    if (empty($_POST['difficulty'])) {
        $difficulty = null;
    
    if (empty($_POST['usedbefore'])) {
            $usedbefore = null;}
    else {
            $difficulty = $_POST['difficulty'];
            $usedbefore = $_POST['usedbefore'];```

Comment: Where you open and close the blocks after if end else there appears to make not that much sense either (referring to your original code now.)  If those to parameters are empty, you are setting the corresponding variables to null, and that’s it - only _inside_ of the else branch, you actually proceed with making the database query. Not sure that is actually the logic you wanted to implement.

Comment: I will try to clarify a bit what I am trying to achieve: If the radio buttons are left unchecked, I would still like the rest of the search query to run. In addition to that, even if the radiobuttons are left unchecked, I would still like the the variables they reference (difficulty and usedbefore) to be displayed in the search result. 

I.e: User inputs search query, doesn't check radio buttons. Result: Rows matching query are displayed. Along side is also the remaining information for that row, even if that information did not match the search query.

Comment: If you want to make the query in any case, then it does not belong into the else block, but after it.

Comment: Okay, I realize now that I was referring to two different issues, I apologize. I issue of the variables not showing up in the result was an unrelated issue to the undefined variable problem. I had forgotten to remove the isset from ``` $difficulty = isset($row['difficulty']);```, so that it returned the bool and not the value of the variable.

It seems that checking the radiobuttons remain quite difficult, so I will simply have one selected by default and move past the issue for now. Thanks for your feedback and help @04FS, otherwise I wouldn't have realized it was two issues